# Solving Cost Minimization with CES Production Function and Two Types of Input

Tags: cost-functions, ces-function

A CES aggregator: $y=\left(\int_{0}^{1} y(i)^{\frac{\eta-1}{\eta}} d i\right)^{\frac{\eta}{\eta-1}}$, where $i \in[0,1]$.

For each intermediate good: $y(i)=\ell_{r}(i)+\ell_{c}(i) / a(i)$, where $a(i)$ is increasing in $i$ and $a(0)=1$. Therefore there is a threshold of using each type of input, $I=\left\{i \in[0,1] \mid w_{c} a(I)=w_{r}\right\} .$

Minimize the unit cost: $$c_{y}=\min _{y(i)} w_{r}\int_{I}^{1} y(i) d i+w_{c} \int_{0}^{I} a(i) y(i) d i$$ s.t. $\left(\int_{0}^{1} y(i)^{\frac{\eta-1}{\eta}} d i\right)^{\frac{\eta}{\eta-1}}=1$.

The result should be $$c_{y}\left(w_{r}, w_{c}\right)=\left(w_{r}^{1-\eta}\left(1-I^{*}\right)+\int_{0}^{I}\left(w_{c} a(i)\right)^{1-\eta} d i\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\eta}}$$.

My try:

For $i \in [I, 1]$, $\bar{y} = \left(\frac{w_r}{\lambda}\right)^{-\eta}$

For $i \in [0, I]$, $y(i) = \left(\frac{a(i)w_c}{\lambda}\right)^{-\eta}$

$\frac{y(i)}{\bar{y}} = \left(\frac{w_c a(i)}{w_r}\right)^{-\eta}$

$(1-I)\bar{y}^{\frac{\eta-1}{\eta}} + \left(\frac{w_c}{w_r}\right)^{1-\eta} \bar{y}^{\frac{\eta-1}{\eta}} \int_0^I a(i)^{1-\eta} =1 $

$\bar{y} = \left(1-I+ \left(\frac{w_c}{w_r}\right)^{1-\eta} \int_{0}^{I} a(i)^{1-\eta} \right)^{\frac{\eta}{1-\eta}}$

I try to replace back $\bar{y}$ and $y(i)$ to $c_y$ but I fail to get above result.

**Update**: I try again replace $\bar{y}$ and $y(i)$ to $c_y$ and find if you rearrange the messy equation really hard it actually can achieve above equation. Like a magic.

Comment: In order to have more possibilities for your question to get solved you can tag Mathematical economics as well!